# Homework questions involving complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

Homework questions:

Additionally, how would you determine that {z belonging to $|z+i|=|z-i|$} is a line?

How would you represent $w(z)=x^{2} + 2ixy - y^{2}$ graphically?

How would you express $-2cis(-\frac{\pi}{6})$ in rectangular form? Clearly the radius is $\pi/6$ but how do you get $z$ to be  $-2$?

Thankful for help!!

Comment: To the first question. Multiply i on both top and bottom.

Comment: Additionally to what? Are you just quoting the assignment mid-question?

Comment: No. I'm saying that it's an additional questions I need help with. I'm not leaving out details. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: $\text{ I think } (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 \text{ could be a good hint on  the 2nd one } \\ \text{ disclaimer: don't have too much experience with graphing complex number stuff }$

Comment: @Jeff As a rule, each question here should be independent. There is no reason to suspect that the person reading this question has read your prior question, so the word "additionally" is apt to be confusing, and give the feeling that something is missing. It i acceptable, if you need to reference a prior question, to link to it, but the text should be clearer than this. Something like, "In addition to my previous question(s),.." Here, you don't need the reference, so just ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

$-2 cis(- \frac{ \pi}{6}) \text{ is what I think you mean for that third question } \\ -2 cis(-\frac{\pi}{6})=-2(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{6})+i \sin(\frac{- \pi}{6})) \\ r=-2 \text{  actually but anyways to get it in rectangular form } \\ \text{ evaluate the } \cos(-\frac{\pi}{6}) \text{ and the } \sin(-\frac{\pi}{6})$

Comment: Thank you for that correction!

Comment: So wait the correct answer would be sqrt 3 + -1/2(i) right?

Comment: $-2(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-i \frac{1}{2}) \\ \text{ distribute the -2 to both terms in the ( ) } $